# crystal letter - send to different people dependent on age

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to write a report that if the patient is less than 18, I want the letter to go to the subscriber but if the patient is 18 or greater, I want the report to go to the patient.

How can I do this using the birth date and current date?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us a code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula {@ADDRESS} with the following and place it in whichever section you want your name and address fields to show.

```
if (Roundup((CurrentDate - {Table.DOB}/ 365)-1) <= 17)
    then {@GUARDIAN}
         else {@PATIENT}
```

Create a formula for each {@GUARDIAN} and {@PATIENT} and put the appropriate address fields in each. Use **&** to concatenate multiple fields and use **"<\br>"** to insert a line break. Lastly, ensure you **Format Field > Paragragh > Text Interpretation > HTML** otherwise it won't display properly.

This will give you your desired results.